# Solving systems of second order differential equations

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica, waveform, differential-equations

I'm working on a script in mathematica that will take simulate a string held at either end and plucked, by solving the wave equation via numerical methods. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Investigation_by_numerical_methods)

```
n = 5; (*The number of discreet elements to be used*)
L = 1.0;  (*The length of the string that is vibrating*)
a = 1.0/3.0; (*The distance from the left side that the string is \
plucked at*)
 T = 1; (*The tension in the string*)
[Rho] = 1; (*The length density of the string*)
y0 = 0.1; (*The vertical distance of the string pluck*)
[CapitalDelta]x = L/n; (*The length of each discreet element*)
m = ([Rho]*L)/n;(*The mass of each individual node*)
c = Sqrt[T/[Rho]];(*The speed at which waves in the string propogate*)
```

I set all my variables

```
Y[t] = Array[f[t], {n - 1, 1}];
MatrixForm(*Creates a vector size n-1 by 1 of functions \
representing each node*)
```

I define my Vector of nodal position functions

```
K = MatrixForm[
SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> -2, Band[{2, 1}] -> 1, 
Band[{1, 2}] -> 1}, {n - 1, 
n - 1}]](*Creates a matrix size n by n governing the coupling \
between each node*)
```

I create the stiffness matrix relating all the nodal functions to one another

```
Y0 = MatrixForm[
Table[Piecewise[{{(((i*L)/n)*y0)/a, 
  0 < ((i*L)/n) < a}, {(-((i*L)/n)*y0)/(L - a) + (y0*L)/(L - a), 
  a < ((i*L)/n) < L}}], {i, 1, n - 1}]]
```

I define the initial positions of each node using a piecewise function

```
NDSolve[{Y''[t] == (c/[CapitalDelta]x)^2 Y[t].K, Y[0] == Y0, 
Y'[0] == 0}, 
Y, {t, 0, 10}];(*Numerically solves the system of second order DE's*)
```

Finally, This should solve for the values of the individual nodes, but it returns an error:

"NDSolve::ndinnt : Initial condition [Y0 table] is not a number or a rectangular array"

So , it would seem that I don't have a firm grasp on how matrices work in mathematica.  I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me get this last line of code to run properly.

Thank you,
Brad

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use `MatrixForm` when defining the matrices. `MatrixForm` is used to format a list of list as a matrix, usually when you display it. Try removing it and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! that helped push me further in the right direction (I think).  Now I'm getting a "NDSolve::ndnum : Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t==0" error, and I can't figure out which part of it has undefined variables.